DAX Expression - MAX
I am having a trouble creating a measure ( or column ) I need for a report. Below, you see my example table. I have an event ID, Date, Rating, RatingDate and Consecutive Count. The Date is just event date. The RatingDate is key here. What I'm trying to calculate is for any given month, how many consecutive days were there with rating of 4 or 5. In this example it is 10. But my measure is showing 1. It's just pulling the last day of the month for some reason. I need it to say 10. I've tried MAX but it needs a column, which I'm unsure how to do. See my DAX below. Any ideas how to get the MAX per month? Also if I don't have a month filter, can it also show the max number of consecutive days for the entire table?

DAX for Consecutive Days measure:
Conescutive Count =
VAR RefDate =
    MAX ( 'Calendar'[Date] )
VAR AllDates =
    ALL ( 'Calendar'[Date] )
VAR DatesWithGreens =
    CALCULATETABLE ( VALUES ( 'Rate the Day'[RatingDate] ), ALLSELECTED () )
VAR DatesWithNoGreens =
    EXCEPT ( AllDates, DatesWithGreens )
VAR NearestHole =
    MAXX (
        FILTER ( DatesWithNoGreens, 'Calendar'[Date] <= RefDate ),
        'Calendar'[Date]
    )
VAR Result =
    INT ( RefDate - NearestHole )
RETURN
    Result


I feel like I'm missing something... You say that you already have a Consecutive Count column and want to show the highest value on a card. Why do you need a measure for that? Dragging that column and selecting MAX of Consecutive Count doesn't do what you require?

Hard to determine which columns are from which tables in your visual above. In the table visual above, are all the columns from the one data table?

@SamNseir, they are all from the same table except where I'm getting all dates. That's just a simple calendar dimension table.

@PhobosFerro No it doesn't. Using MAX requires a column, which this is not. The consecutive count column is a measure. That is my issue. I'm not sure how to get the MAX of that measure. I'm open to other suggestions then what I'm doin here.

You could do this as one measure but I will suggest you do this as two measures for simplicity and manageability.
Create this one measure which won't be used in visuals so you can hide it if you like:
row Consecutive Count = 
  var thisDate = MAX('Rate the Day'[Date])
  var lastHole = 
    CALCULATE(
      MAX('Rate the Day'[Date]),
      ALLSELECTED('Rate the Day'),
      'Rate the Day'[Date] <> 'Rate the Day'[RatingDate] && 'Rate the Day'[Date] <= thisDate
    )
  var noHole = CALCULATE(  MIN('Rate the Day'[Date]), ALLSELECTED('Rate the Day') )
  var fromDate = COALESCE(lastHole, noHole - 1)
  return DATEDIFF(fromDate, thisDate, DAY)

(The above measure is a variation to the one you have).
Create this second measure that you will use for visuals:
Consecutive Count = 
  IF(
    ISINSCOPE('Rate the Day'[RatingDate]),
    [row Consecutive Count],
    MAXX('Rate the Day', [row Consecutive Count])
  )


